# Ajax network error message popup is unreadable with new theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message

Sorry could not get a screenie, but the text and background is almost the same color, making the message unreadable.

This happened while editing tags.

**Update**: The supposed fix is not working, I managed to get a screenshot.

[image: badstyling]

**Update 2**: Played with the image colors to make the message readable in the image.

[image]

**Update 3**: Here's the source code of the box, it might help to locate the issue:

```
<div class="message-inner">
    <div class="message-close" title="close this message (or hit Esc)">×</div>
    <div style="padding-right: 35px;" class="message-text">
        <title>Network Error</title>

        <font face="Helvetica">
            <big><strong></strong></big><br>
        </font>
        <blockquote>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" width="80%">
            <tbody><tr><td>
            <font face="Helvetica">
            <big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
            <br>
            <br>
            </font>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <font face="Helvetica">
            A communication error occurred: ""
            </font>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <font face="Helvetica">
            The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
            </font>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <font face="Helvetica" size="2">
            <br>
            For assistance, contact your network support team.
            </font>
            </td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What tag were you trying to add in this screenshot?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: It is not tag related, but I gotten mostly when clicking 'Save' after I edited tags.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed on live. Please let me know if it's still broken for you.

Comment: Thanks, a bit hard to simulate without some trickery, but will look out for it.

Comment: Fix not working, managed to get a screenshot.

Comment: Unrelated, but when is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283937/contrast-on-highlighted-favorites-is-too-low) going to be fixed? Seems like it should be real simple to fix by just changing the "tagged-interesting" class...

Comment: I agree... Still bloody broken... @Jin Perhaps a post edit and a downvote can get your attention :D

Comment: @leppie My apologies. I thought I fixed it, but turned out I fixed the wrong bug. Could you tell me how to reproduce this bug?

Comment: @Jin: I think it happens when you get an network error from an ajax request. Not easy to repro at all :(

Comment: @leppie I confirm the ajax issue, I just got one. would it it help if I describe the HTML structure of the window message?

Comment: I've hadded the code of the message in the question. btw, you should consider removing the `status-completed` tag, shouldn't you ?